# Query for a financial balance with a PROC SQL in SAS?

Tags: sql, sas, proc-sql

I have two tables, first call it "transactions"

| transaction_id | transaction_type | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 1 | 50.00 |
| 102 | 2 | 25.00 |
| 103 | 3 | 35.00 |
| 104 | 2 | 15.00 |
| 105 | 1 | 60.00 |

and second call it "transaction_types"

| id | description |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Deposit |
| 2 | Retirement |
| 3 | Inner_transaction |

The "id" column in the "transaction_types" table, corresponds with the "transsaction_id" in the first table

Suppose that the initial balance is $100,000.00. I should write a query to get the historical account balance. The table that I should show is this:

| transaction_id | initial_balance | deposit | withdrawal | final_balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 100000 | 50.00 |  | 100050 |
| 102 | 100050 |  | 25.00 | 100025 |
| 103 | 100025 |  |  | 100025 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

I write this code in SAS using a PROC SQL:

```
TITLE "Balance Historico de la Wallet Empresarial";
PROC SQL;
    SELECT transaction_id,
           100000 AS initial_balance FORMAT=DOLLAR32.2,
           "" AS deposit,
           "" AS withdrawal,
           "" AS final_balance
    FROM _LIB.TRANSACTIONS;
QUIT;
```

But I don't know how fill the other columns.

Comment: Edit your question with tags for ONE database that you are actually using. Its obviously not MySQL.

Comment: Are there really only 3 transaction types?  Why do you need a separate table for that?

Comment: Why would you want to do this in SQL instead of a DATA step?

Answer (score 0):

Consider conditional aggregation where you assign new columns conditionally and then aggregate by needed grouping. Use `calculated` clause to complete needed final balance arithmetic.

```sql
TITLE "Balance Historico de la Wallet Empresarial"; 

PROC SQL; 
   SELECT transaction_id
        , initial_balance FORMAT=DOLLAR32.2
        , SUM(deposit) AS deposit FORMAT=DOLLAR32.2
        , SUM(withdrawal) AS withdrawal FORMAT=DOLLAR32.2
        , initial_balance + 
          calculated deposit - 
          calculated withdrawal AS final_balance FORMAT=DOLLAR32.2
  FROM 
   (SELECT ts.transaction_id
         , 100000 AS initial_balance
         , CASE WHEN tt.description = 'Deposit' THEN ts.amount ELSE NULL END AS deposit
         , CASE WHEN tt.description = 'Withdrawal' THEN ts.amount ELSE NULL END AS withdrawal
         , CASE WHEN tt.description = 'Inner_balance' THEN ts.amount ELSE NULL END AS inner_balance
    FROM _LIB.TRANSACTIONS ts
    INNER JOIN _LIB.TRANSACTION_TYPES tt
       ON ts.transaction_type = tt.id
   ) sub
  GROUP BY transaction_id
         , initial_balance;
QUIT;
```

Alternatively, with SAS SQL dialect, use [`IFN`](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/lefunctionsref/n0l3n5z2h31h7wn1fmnqd33ibhap.htm) for slightly shorter syntax:

```sql
  ...
  , IFN(tt.description = 'Deposit', ts.amount, .) AS deposit
  , IFN(tt.description = 'Withdrawal', ts.amount, .) AS withdrawal
  , IFN(tt.description = 'Inner_balance', ts.amount, .) AS inner_balance
  ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much Parfait, but  I still have a question:
How does the "Group by" statement work in this case, since if I only group by the "transaction_id" field I get the same result. I do not understand why?

Comment: Parfait, I can't make the initial_balance update according to the final_balance, could you help me?

Comment: What results when your run this query?